# Determine which devices are connected to a switch

Tags: networking, linux-networking

As can be seen in the diagram [image] I have a device that is serving DHCP on a network where multiple other devices are connected via different switches. I was wondering if it is possible to determine which devices are connected to the same switch. For example, in this case, it would be that devices 1 & 2 are connected to the same switch, and devices 3 & 4 are connected to the same switch and so on. I guess another way to look at this is to determine which devices are connected on the same port on the switch that is directly connected to the DHCP server. Is there a way to find this out on the linux server?

Comment: Do you know what model(s) the switches are? If they're non-smart (a.k.a. dumb switches), it's nearly impossible.

Comment: I will find out if they are smart switches. To add more information also, I have full control of all devices in the network, they are all linux devices that I can modify the code of.. so if I can add some smarts to those devices maybe there's a way?

Comment: Your *switches* needs to report this somehow. It can be by acting as DHCP relays, or by a separate protocol such as SNMP where you can look up clients - or you can look up manually in the CLI.